# What are the uses of overnight loans?

Tags: debt

As far as I understand an overnight loan is a loan that is settled the next day.

Who are the entities that would find it useful to take a loan just for a day? and, what would they use an overnight loan for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overnight_market

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Main users of overnight lending are banks. Banks have large in- and out-flows from customers on a daily basis. They typically borrow to meet a temporary outflow.
- There is a term premium for borrowing at longer terms. By implication, borrowing overnight is theoretically the cheapest financing cost. Financial entities will borrow overnight to finance portfolios.